# Update URL's Inside Documents After Migration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, migration, content-migration, document-migration

Is there an elegant recommended way or tool that allows updating URL's inside documents in SharePoint 2013 after a migration?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for the tool / script to update links (URLs) referred in the wiki pages after migration. If you are looking for a tool to migrate across SharePoint and replace the URLs inside the pages (web parts), then you can take a look at Vyapin’s **[XPlica for SharePoint](http://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-to-sharepoint/xplica/sharepoint-migration-tools-and-software)**.

If you are looking for a tool / script to update the URLs in the web pages alone after migration, then I will give you the below PowerShell script that will help you to replace the old links with the new links with respect to target location.

```
Param([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][alias("Url")]$SPWebUrl, [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][alias("ListName")]$SPListName, [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][alias("Search")]$SearchString, [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][alias("Replace")]$ReplaceString)
```

## Add SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn if not already added

```
if((Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}
```

## Get SharePoint website object

```
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb $SPWebUrl
```

## Get SharePoint list object

```
$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists[$SPListName]
```

## Iterate through each item in the Wiki Library

```
foreach($SPListItem in $SPList.Items)
{
```

## Check if $SPListItem contains $SearchString

```
if($SPListItem["ows_WikiField"] -and  $SPListItem["ows_WikiField"].contains($SearchString))
{
```

## Check out page

```
$SPListItem.File.CheckOut();
```

## Replace $Search_String with $Replace_String and update item

```
$SPListItem["ows_WikiField"] = $SPListItem["ows_WikiField"].replace($SearchString, $ReplaceString);
$SPListItem.Update();
```

## Check in page

```
$SPListItem.File.CheckIn("Checked in by system");
Write-Host "Completed"
}
}
```

**Note:** Run the PowerShell as Administrator on the target SharePoint server and execute the above script using Windows PowerShell.

Comment: not only in Wiki pages.  I am really looking for a script that updates URL's inside .doc and .docx files.